# Display MySQL database using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

Is it any way to display MySQL Database using JQuery? I want to display each data in a range time (for example 5 seconds) and then change automatically to other data.

I have this data

```
ID  Name    Text
1   Iqbal   Text from Iqbal
2   Yudi    Text from Yudi
3   Zizan   Text from Zizan
```

It should be like this

```
Iqbal   Text from Iqbal
```

and after 5 seconds, it will change to

```
Yudi  Text from Yudi
```

and so on.

I have tried using JQuery, but i am facing difficult to use it with data that already fetched in PHP code. Is it any way to call **fetched data** from PHP and **display it in JQuery**?

**This is php/MySql code**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="boxed" style="height:200px; border:1px solid #CCCC99; background:#CCCC99; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jos_news ORDER BY id DESC");

    echo "<div id='news'>
<table border='0' height='175px' width='180px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border-radius:10px; border:1px solid #FFFFFF; background-color:#FFFFFF;' >";     

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {

    echo "<tr> <td align='right'><b>". $row['Text'] ."</b></td> </tr>";

      }

    echo "</table></div>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**and this is jquery script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hna-consulting.com/hafizi-associates/templates/template_v5/jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        SliderInt=1;
        SliderNext=1;

        $("document").ready(function(){
           $(".boxed #news").fadeIn(10000);
           startSlider();

        });

        function startSlider(){
           loop = setInterval (function(){
             $(".boxed #news").fadeOut(300);

           },3000)

        }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery cannot connect directly to database. However, you can make a php file to get results and then call that page via AJAX.

Comment: what if i create an array from database. Is it possible to call array with JQuery?

Comment: You will create it using which tools? That's what being suggested, you will need some server side programming language to prepare that array for jQuery.

Comment: fyi: i already fetched the data in my php code. not using jquery to access directly to database.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted jQuery can not access the database, also from the code you have posted it seems that you are aware of that since you access the db with php and only use jquery to fade in fade out data.

So what you have done so far is ok but you need to hide all data echoed by php and let jquery parse the data and only display/fade in the rows you need. Then fade out the last shown data and fade in the next rows you want to display. This way you create a cycle of the latest news.

Judging from your query i assume you are using joomla so i propose another solution which works well and saves you from the server side trouble.  Create an article (or item if you use cck like k2 etc) or module that holds the latest news. If it is an article assign that to a menu item that is not visilbe to your site, but published (this is a common technique with joomla to create nice urls of content or simply have access to data as in your case). If it is a module add it to the page you desire (it is the page where the jquery code is executed) but assign a class name to it in order to hide this module via css i.e. using `display:none`.

This will save you from maintaining the server side code, which already has some issues as far as i can see i.e. you should not use prefixes in joomla queries to db, you should use the joomla way of accessing the db etc.

Also this way you can manage the content from your cms i.e. show only latest news, or news from a specific category etc without writing any server side code and without having to modify your sql query.

Finally you write jquery code that screen scrapes/parses the contents of that article or module and appends the data to any div you like with any effect you require i.e. fade in , fade out etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get data from mysql using jquery directly, it is the server side code (php) work, you can make calls to that php code by jquery.

And Yes it is possible to display the data like you explained. You can use JQuery Cycle Plugin, which has such feature.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Checkout the examples and demos. Instead of images, you just put those data from MySQL database.

Comment: On which of their pages do they mention that their jQuery can connect to database directly without any server side programming language? can you please give me a link. I would love to learn how to do so if that is possible. And I'm kinda being sarcastic here :)

Comment: haha, i did not mentioned that you can connect to mysql using jquery, did I ? :P . I only gave the link to scroll automatically the data, not to fetch from DB. That is the server side code thing. He already fetched the data in php, if you check his code. I think i should change my answer a little bit.